# How to delete the following characters in a string with python?

Tags: python, string

How can I delete the following characters in a string: '.SW'. Characters to remove are '.SW' in the following example:

```
stock = 'RS2K.SW'
original_string = stock
characters_to_remove = ".SW"
new_string = original_string
for character in characters_to_remove:
   new_string = new_string.replace(character, "")
stocketf = new_string
print (stocketf)
```

Result should be:
`RS2K`

My actual wrong result is:
`R2K`

Comment: you can directly replace the full substring: `new_string = stock.replace(characters_to_remove, "")`, with current approach, every occurrence of `S` is getting removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to choose from as the existing answers demonstrate. Another way, if these characters always come at the end, could be to just split your string on the '.' character and keep the first section:

```
stock = 'RS2K.SW'
new_string = stock.split(.)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it looks like that you could just remove the last three characters.

```
my_str = my_str[:-3]
```

Otherwise, I would suggest using Regex

Answer (score 0):

In this case this should be a valid solution for your answer:

```
stock = 'RS2K.SW'
original_string = stock
characters_to_remove = ".SW"
new_string = 
stock[:original_string.index(characters_to_remove)]
print(new_string)
```